# Change ImageView dynamically knowing file name from database

Tags: android, imageview, android-sqlite

In my application I am getting the filename dynamically from database but I'm not sure how to update the image of ImageView.

Let's say I have this code:

```
String str = "image2.jpg";
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
```

How could I set the image to be `image2.jpg`, if current image is another?

PS. In my application, I have a spinner. Every time the selected element is changed, I make a database request and I get the image name, and I need to modify image of imageview dynamically.

Comment: For this you need to get the path instead of filename then you can set it to imageview..

Comment: ok.. can you give me an example please ? is it ok to store image in drawable folders? or should i create another folder storing my images? i'm newbie

Comment: yes you can place the images in the drawable folder..and store their ids in database..

Comment: ok..wait i will post my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a method like this in your Activity

```
public Drawable getImage(String name) {
    return getResources().getDrawable(
            getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable",
                    getPackageName()));
}
```

pass you image name here you will get drawable object then set it to Imageview

```
    Drawable image = getImage(name);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
```

Comment: ok, then how should i know that integer value when inserting it in database ? I only know the name of the file from drawable folder like "image.jpg" and this is actually stored in database. I am not sure if I am able to insert an integer number in database as i don't know it.

I actually add the file manually in the drawable folder. And I insert manually the rows in database.

Comment: i have written one metod just copy that method and call that method whenevar you want to set image

Comment: I am now trying to make it work. I have some errors :) I will accept your answer, but just wait few more mins to make sure it's ok. Actually it throws some exceptions. I need to debug.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44060/discussion-between-smotru-and-kalyan-pvs)